# How to separate words into letters in app inventor 2

Tags: android

I'm doing an encryption device for an school project and I need a way to separate words into individual letters in order to replace them with a symbol.

Does anyone know how to use the blocks of app inventor 2 to separate a word of a text into single letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Blocks Text built-ins, you can use the `split` block.  The split `at` can be set to an empty text input (basically "") which means split at every letter.  The results can be processed with a `for each item in list` block.

Here is a crude example taking the input from a TextBox and outputing one letter per line into a second Multiline TextBox.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Do you know how to group the letters (which now i have substituted into other letters) into words again? For example: I have written apple, the in separated it into a p p l e then i asigned every letter a a substitute (h l l o r) h=a, l=p. o= l, e= r. And now i want the letters to come back together (hllor). Pls take into account that it is intended to be used in phrases. I just need a way to make the letters form the original word.

Comment: Use `join` with an empty separater "" to join the letters back into a contiguous block.